# Powershell format-volume fails with drive is read only error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to format a volume from powershell. When I tried the command on a test volume, the operation fails with below error.

> format-volume : Cannot perform the requested operation when the drive
>   is read only

[image]

I looked at the disk and volume attributes in command line and both have the "read-only" attribute as "no".

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me here ?

Comment: Is your shell elevated with the UAC?

Comment: yes, powershell is running as administrator

Comment: People in comments [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/29/use-powershell-to-initialize-raw-disks-and-to-partition-and-format-volumes/) are assuming that it could be a conflict when a formatting is starting to early, before a partitioning is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this error when the disk being formatted has an 'active' page-file on it.

Move the Page file to another volume, reboot, and the problem should be solved.